# Trigger not firing if insert is inside a transaction

Tags: mysql, triggers, transactions, mysql-workbench

I wrote a trigger to automatically update a date on **donator** table row after inserting a new row on my **donation** table. The problem is, it is not updating the date in **donator** as I expected

The trigger seems to work if I do an insert outside a transaction, though.

Here's the trigger:

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER updateDate AFTER INSERT ON donation
FOR EACH ROW
    UPDATE donator
        SET Next_Date = DATE_ADD(NEW.Donation_Date, INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
    WHERE id_Donator = NEW.Donator_id_Donator
$$
```

And here's the transaction:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE RegisterDonation (in QuantityArg INT, in Donation_DateArg DATE, in Donator_idArg INT)
    BEGIN


        DECLARE exit handler for SQLEXCEPTION
            BEGIN
                SHOW ERRORS LIMIT 1;
                SHOW WARNINGS;
                ROLLBACK;
            END;
        DECLARE exit handler for SQLWARNING
            BEGIN
                SHOW ERRORS LIMIT 1;
                SHOW WARNINGS;
                ROLLBACK;
            END;

        START TRANSACTION;

            set @next_id := ifnull((select max(Donation_id) from donation) + 1, 1);


            INSERT INTO donation(Donation_id, Quantity, Donation_Date, Donator_id_Donator) VALUES
                (@next_id, QuantityArg, Donation_DateArg, Donator_idArg);

        COMMIT;

    END
$$
```

I know I could just update the date inside the transaction but I have other triggers and it doesn't sound like a good solution to just copy paste the code into every single transaction. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @krishKM there is a well known `ifnull()` function: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya thx.. added to my list :)

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem and I would expect a trigger to fire within a transaction. Can you add the initial set up for donators and some call statements to back up your claim.BTW if you are expecting the trigger to create a donator record then an update statement won't do that, your logic assumes donator records exist before donations are accepted.

Comment: Welp, I fixed it. Closed workbench, restarted computer, opened workbench, tried it and suddenly the trigger is working. Why, I don't know, but I lost 2 hours debugging this.